# Bind backbone event to a multiple class selector

Tags: backbone-events

I can't get the following event to attach to my  element.

```
events = {
   "change .date-selector .date-range": "dateRangeSelectionChanged"
}
```

Is this supported at all in Backbone.js? Or am I using a wrong syntax?

Comment: your syntax looks fine: http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: Are you able to go to the console window and use jQuery to select your elements. $(".date-selector .date-range").length this should return at least 1.  Also check to see if the dateRangeSelectionChanged has the correct spelling and camel case format.  I would also check either using the developer tools in IE or FireBug in FireFox and check to see if you see any error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To select upon multiple classes you should use:

```
events = { "change .date-selector.date-range": "dateRangeSelectionChanged" }
```

Note the removed space between classes

Comment: Yes, the extra space seems to be the problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is NOT required anymore. Spaces are now handled appropriately by Backbone. Refer the examples: http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents  (The actual problem for me was that the view wasn't attached to the DOM object.)

Comment: Use @techvineet answer, since this one is out dated.

Comment: How this is outdated? @hharnisc

Answer (score 23):

You can separate the selectors by comma(',')

```
events: { "change .date-selector,.date-range": "dateRangeSelectionChanged" }
```

Comment: Good tip. However, I think that would do a logical `OR` than `AND`, to do and `AND` selector separate them by dots and no spaces in between. Please correct me if I'm wrong as I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have an equals operator where you should have ':'

```
App.Namespeace.BestViewEver = Backbone.View.extend({
  events : { 
    "change .date-selector .date-range": "dateRangeSelectionChanged"
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention that this is TypeScript code and equal sign is valid there. I don't have it anymore in my app so don't know what was the problem but Kalpers' comment is useful.